# Что быстрее, читать файл несколько раз или один раз и занести в массив?

Tags: python, производительность

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какая из программ будет работать быстрее:

1. Программа, читающая один и тот же файл несколько раз и работает с данными, не занося их в массив;
2. Программа, которая читает файл один раз, заносит полученные данные в массив и в дальнейшем уже работает с ним?

Файл может содержать 50-100 тысяч чисел, каждое из которых предстоит обработать.

Comment: количество данных небольшое разницы особо не увидите, мне кажется 2 вариант будет быстрее так как чтение файлов довольно долгая операция, а так замеряйте критические участки кода и используйте эту информацию для дальнейшей оптимизации

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Работа с данными в памяти понятно быстрее, чем работа с файлами. Но возможны нюансы.
- Если оперативной памяти для хранения данных недостаточно, то держать данные в памяти может оказаться медленнее - система будет активно писать и читать своп-файл чтобы освободить память и вся экономия съестся.
- Или наоборот может быть так, что памяти много, файл небольшой и операционная система его целиком кеширует в памяти и читает оттуда. Тогда чтение файла будет практически таким же быстрым, как чтение из памяти.
- Ещё нужно учитывать формат, в котором вы храните в файле данные. Если это текстовые данные которые потом ещё нужно преобразовать из строк в числа, то это довольно затратная операция и вот экономия на ней в случае хранения данных в памяти может оказаться существенной в любом случае.

Answer (score 3):

Небольшое дополнение к отличному ответу @CrazyElf.

Кроме того, что вы можете значительно ускорить работу с данными, работая с данными в памяти, вы также можете:

- значительно ускорить изначальную загрузку данных из файла если сохранить данные в бинарном виде. Например чтение данных из файла в Parquet или Pickle формате может быть в 10 раз быстрее по сравнению с чтением CSV файла. Причиной тому необходимость угадывать правильные типы данных и преобразование строк в правильные типы данных.
- если в дальнейшем хранить (в памяти) и обрабатывать прочитанные данные используя векторизированные модули Pandas / Numpy вместо циклов, можно еще на несколько порядков ускорить работу с данными в памяти.

Answer (score 1):

Тут логика простая: при считывании файла ваша программа обращается к диску, если на компе стоит SSD (твердотельный накопитель) то это еще относительно быстро, то в случае с HDD (винчестер) процесс в разы медленнее. При загрузке данных в массив - у вас они хранятся в оперативке (DDR), а скорость работы с ней в разы выше чем даже с SSD.

**Ответ очевиден:** быстрее будет работать программа, которая читает файл один раз и заносит полученные данные в массив.

Comment: А если это ещё и сетевой диск, то вообще...